# Object reference not set to... IN COMMAND IN COLLECTIONVIEW

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a collectionview and command.The problem is that when I read the object to the command it is for some reason zero, sorry and please help where the error

XAML

```
              <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MyPins}"  x:Name="ListPlaces"    
                   SelectionMode="None">

        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="10"/>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                           <Frame HasShadow="True" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  BorderColor="#E5E5E5" CornerRadius="10"  VerticalOptions="Start">
                        <StackLayout  Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer     Command="{Binding BindingContext.CallPlace, Source={x:Reference ListPlaces}}"  ></TapGestureRecognizer>
                                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <Label x:Name="NameOfPlace" Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="#2D78FD" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Robobo"/>
                            <Label x:Name="AdressOfPlace" Text="{Binding Address}"  TextColor="#616161" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Robobo"/>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label x:Name="TimeWork" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Open until  -  "  TextColor="#616161" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Robobo"/>
                                            <Label x:Name="TimeWork1" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Opened}"  TextColor="#616161" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Robobo"/>
                                            <Image Source="openIcon" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                <Button HeightRequest="24" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="0,-3,0,0" WidthRequest="92" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" FontSize="14" CornerRadius="45" BackgroundColor="#2D78FD" TextColor="White" Text="Call up"/>
                            </StackLayout>

                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
               
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
public PlacesList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext =  this;
            CallPlace = new Command<CustomPin>((key) =>
            {
             var currentPlace = key as CustomPin;
             MapPage.PlacesHandler(currentPlace);
             
            });

        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass data into the Command using the CommandParameter property

```
 <TapGestureRecognizer   CommandParameter={Binding .}  Command="{Binding BindingContext.CallPlace, Source={x:Reference ListPlaces}}"  />
```

Assuming CustomPin is the type of list object that you are binding to this CollectionView.

Also, use the XAML styler Vs extension it's free and it makes your XAML really presentable
every time you save a file

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TeamXavalon.XAMLStyler